# can jQuery load,post,get methods receive a var=value response?

Tags: jquery, post

i've been playing around w/ these things and it seems that the callback function has only one response variable..

```
$.post(link, $("#form").serializeArray(), sendFormResponse);
```

where sendFormResponse function does the magic ...

however i have only 1 variable (response) to play with..

i needed at least 2

if i could get this .post method to return 2 variables:
1) status = (ok,error,adjust, etc)
2) statusMessage (or response) =  (more strings)

both of w/c are generated from php side, that would be super.. coz i can evaluate what to do depending on my php's responses..

Comment: you can return an array which has multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument passed to the callback (or returned in the response) can be an object, which can have unlimited properties or an array containing multiple elements.

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking at data in the success method. Usually I would setup a standard response json object which I can validate myself.

```
$.post('ajax/test.php', function(response) {
  if (response.success) {
      alert(response.data.key1);
      // will display "value1"
  } else {
      alert(response.errorText);
  }
});
```

test.php

```
<?php
// so ajax client can interpret content appropriately
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// hide all php notices/warnings/errors 
// (you really should be logging them)
// ** Any text other than the json encoded string
// will break the clients parsing abilities **
ini_set('display_errors', false);


$response = array(
    "success" => true,
    "errorText" => "",
    "data" => array(
        "key1" => "value1"
    )
);

echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Comment: im getting an undefined response this this one as well.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: hmm.. ok i got it to work but not w/ post.. but w/  .getJSON.. but shouldnt this work w/ .post?

Comment: ok now that i added "header('Content-Type: application/json');" before the output from my php, JS side is reading jsons properly both from .post and .getJSON calls

.. only thing that annoys me though is i have to set header('Content-Type: application/json'); before every jason output..

Comment: and yet another issue i found..
while getJSON works.. but if my script somehow konks out gets an error or outputs a non JSON, the darn callback function isnt triggered! so there's no way for me to see the output ERROR in plain text .. i have to output JSON formatted error.. sheesh>>

this JSON thing is getting annoying. i might as well go back to character delimited technique, and parse it..

like
stat and statMsg

ill just do "ok://:form has been process://:"   .. much more straight forward

Comment: But this will always be required if you are sending JSON. Otherwise some browsers will not interpret it as JSON and you will have the kind of problems you have been experiencing.

Comment: ahh ok. well goin w/ you guys  examples here you all didnt initiate json headers on the php side of things so i thought it'd be automatic..

Answer (score 2):

From your PHP send an JSON encoded array

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => 'ok', 'data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2)); //etc.
```

Then you can reference both the success flag and the data in your Javascript.

```
$.post(link, $("#form").serializeArray(), function(data) {
   if (data.success == 'ok') {
       alert('data1 = ' + data.data1);
   } 
   else {
      alert (data.error);
   }
});
```

Comment: I think it's `$.post(link, $("#form").serializeArray(), sendFormResponse);` not `$.post(link, $("#form").serializeArray(), sendFormResponse(data));` As far as I know the `(data)` is omitted when passing a function as an argument or the function is executed right there and then instead. Any parameters are passed automatically when `sendFormResponse` is executed.

Comment: ...decided to go w/ a character delimited return string, where i split into array in JS  

Eg. echo "ok--**--my message here";

lolz..

Comment: Assuming that you are getting just `undefined`, implies that the data.success is not present or != 'ok'.

Comment: well i did just one change to the js function, and that is to change the .post to .getJSON and everything worked as expected.. so definitely my php is outputting JSON and JS is receiving it, it's just that JS doesnt seem to understand the php output unless i explicitly call get.JSON .. perhaps JS treats it as plain text if passed via .post?

Comment: Set a header in PHP `header('Content-Type: application/json;Charset=UTF-8);` this will tell the browser that you are passing back JSON.